# Erro na execução de imagem do activity_main.xml

Tags: java, android, android-studio

recentemente instalei o android studio versao 3.0 e segui as instruções de instalação e configuração dele, porém surgiu esse erro. Desinstalei e reinstalei e persiste na mesma, o que devo fazer?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Pela mensagem parece que você está com versões de dependências conflitantes. Verifique se não foram declaradas mais de uma vez ou se as versões instaladas estão de acordo com o projeto.

Comment: o que seriam essas dependências conflitantes? poderia me explicar?

Answer (score 1):

Parece que no seu arquivo `build.gradle` do seu módulo `app` a dependência `com.android.support:support-annotations` declarada mais de uma vez e com versões diferentes. Aparentemente, você tem essa dependência com a versão `26.1.0` e `17.1.1`. Basta verificar qual a versão do seu `compileSdkVersion`. Caso seja 27, então mude todas as versões das dependências `com.android.support` para 27, caso contrário mude para versão que se encontra.

Se preferir, poste o código do seu `build.gradle` aqui para analisarmos.